# Google Drive Realtime for Desktop Application

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, google-drive-realtime-api

I am investigating the Google Realtime API and I cannot figure out if it is possible to use it in a desktop Java application (using JavaFX)?

I know next to nothing about JavaScript (or web programming in general) yet.. but I obviously need to learn about it.

If I try to load https://apis.google.com/js/api.js via Java's (Nashorn) ScriptEngineManager, I get an error: `"window" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1`

So is it even possible to use the Google Realtime API within a desktop Java application?

Perhaps I can achieve this with the JavaFX WebView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the only way to actually access a JS library is through the use of a Webview. Since Realtime API is currently supported only by Javascript, you can rely on the quickstart 
guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart.

This guide will help you to integrate the HTML content to your project: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXWV135.

Hope it helps!